# ClassCastException when setting onClickListener within Dialog subclass

Tags: android, dialog, classcastexception

I have subclassed Dialog in order to display a popup. This dialog contains a ListView, and so I also have an inner class (in the Dialog) that subclasses BaseAdapter.

I am trying to set the onClickListener for text that is within my list, however I keep getting ClassCastException at setOnClickListener (see code below).

```
 public class CustomDialog extends Dialog
 {
MyAdapter adapter = null;

public CustomDialog(Context context) 
{
    super(context);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_popup);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    adapter = new MyAdapter(context);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


     public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener
     {
       @Override
       public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) 
        {
                ....
            TextView groupText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.mytext);
            mytext.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this); //crashes here
                ....
         }

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
        {
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you're messing with two classes that have the same name but different package....`View.OnClickListener` and `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`. The listener you have in your class is a `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` but you're wanting a `View.OnClickListener`. Change your implement to use `View.OnClickListener` and that'll fix your problem.